# PHP array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
Array
 (
  [0] => hello;string1
  [1] => bye;string2
)
```

I want to get the array so I have the value of the string (after the ;) to be a value of the array key, so it becomes multi dimensional

Comment: `foreach` and `explode` may help you with this task

Comment: show how should look the expected result

Comment: This question show no effort of research or what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = array
 (
  "hello;string1",
  "bye;string2"
);
$newArr = [];
foreach ($arr as $a) {
 $e = explode(";", $a);
    $newArr[$e[1]] = $e[0];
}
print_r($newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using an explode

an [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) explodes a variable on a delimitter, in your case ;
it puts the exploded values inside an array

```
<?php
$arr = ['test;hi', 'another;one'];
$newarr = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

    $value = explode(';', $value);
    $newarr[$value[0]] = $value[1];
}
var_dump($newarr);
```

Output of the var_dump:

```
array(2) { ["test"]=> string(2) "hi" ["another"]=> string(3) "one" }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array=Array
 (
  0 => "hello;string1",
  1 => "bye;string2"
);
$result=array();
foreach($array as $data)
{
    list($value,$key)=explode(";", $data);
    $result[$key]=$value;
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help, this actually what i wanted, sorry for being vague

```
foreach ($arr as $a) {
$e = explode(";", $a);
$newarr[] = array('hello' => $e[0], 'bye' => $e[1]);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use something like this!!

```
$cars = array
(
array("Volvo",22,18),
array("BMW",15,13),
array("Saab",5,2),
array("Land Rover",17,15)
);

for ($row = 0; $row < 4; $row++) {
echo "<p><b>Row number $row</b></p>";
echo "<ul>";
for ($col = 0; $col < 3; $col++) {
echo "<li>".$cars[$row][$col]."</li>";
 }
  echo "</ul>";
 }
```

**Outout**

```
Row number 0

Volvo
22
18
Row number 1

BMW
15
13
Row number 2


Saab
5
2
Row number 3

Land Rover
17
15
```

I fixed my answer to the new code above also you can find it here at https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp

Comment: How exactly is this supposed to answer OP's question?

Comment: Yes in the ideal situation he could have an array like this, but you dont know why he asks this. Maybe he cant change this array and its from an import?

Comment: They are multiple ways to do this, but we don't know why you asked this. You should edit the question to why you need it for cause like I said they're multiple ways to do this and ways to use this for like for getting data from a database.